# windows mobile orientations

Tags: windows-mobile

Hai i am new to windows mobile application i didn't know how  to change orientation in windows mobile can any one explain me how to change it in landscape mode and potrait mode.

Answer (score 0):

Call [ChangeDisplaySettingsEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa923082.aspx) with DM_DISPLAYORIENTATION and the angle you want.

Answer (score 0):

The following table shows the Pocket PC and Smartphone screen orientations supported by the .NET Compact Framework. Dimensions are in pixels, width by height.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229649(VS.80).aspx